# How can I get list of opengl extensions in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

How can I get list of opengl extensions in Android, if I not have reference for GL10 context, and create own one is not an option coz it's to long.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this extension viewer: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realtechvr.glview

or you can query the extensions via this call:

```
 GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS)
```